# PHP : instantiation of an object as a property of a class

Tags: php

i have the line of codes:

```
class foo{
    public $object = new bar(2);

    public function index(){
        dd($this->object);
    }
}
```

and the `bar` object contains:

```
class bar{
    protected $number;

    function __construct($number){
        $this->number = $number;
    }
}
```

now its throwing me `Constant expression contains invalid operation`

Comment: The first example in the docs shows you which values and expressions are valid for instantiating class properties - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php . It's not particularly intuitive what you can and can't do, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not currently possible to instantiate an object during class properties declaration. That should be done in the object constructor instead :

```
class foo{
    public $object;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->object = new bar(2);
    }

    public function index(){
        dd($this->object);
    }
}
```